# Controlling IKEA Tradfri lights from Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I have a home automation system set up using a few Raspberry pi zeros all connected through sockets to a pi b+ that i use to host a web server with PHP running the whole system.

I bought the IKEA Tradfri lights and gateway after seeing that it was possible to control them through the raspberry pi.

I followed the instructions on [Pimoroni](https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/sandyj/controlling-ikea-tradfri-lights-from-your-pi)

I follow the instructions for

> Installing libcoap with support for DTLS

Following the instructions under

> API endpoints

I copy and paste the code:

```
coap-client -m put -u "Client_identity" -k "1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h" -e '{ "3311": [{ "5850": 0 }] }' "coaps://192.168.0.10:5684/15001/65537"
```

Changing the IP address to the IP address of my IKEA tradfri gateway and the security key to the one on the gateway.

I get the following:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/libcoap $ coap-client -m put -u "Client_identity" -k 
"My security key" -e '{ "3311": [{ "5850": 0 }] }' 
"coaps://192.168.0.105:5684/15001/65537"
v:1 t:CON c:PUT i:442d {} [ ]
decrypt_verify(): found 24 bytes cleartext
decrypt_verify(): found 4 bytes cleartext
4.01
```

But nothing seems to happen ..... 
I expect the first light that I connected to the system to turn off

if I try

```
coap-client -m get -u "Client_identity" -k "1a2b3c4d5e6f7g8h" "coaps://192.168.0.10:5684/15001/65537"
```

To try get information about the lights i get the same response.

I don't see any errors so i don't even know where to start with figuring this out.

Any suggestions on what I could do ?

Comment: Your command `coap-client -m put -u "Client_identity" -k` returns `4.01` which is [CoAP for Unauthorised](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-core-coap-04#section-5.9.2). Are you sure that you are using the right identity/psk ?

Answer (score 3):

IKEA Trådfri's firmware update changed in such a way that you must create a new identity for your integration: https://github.com/ggravlingen/pytradfri/issues/90

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it works if you leave the user name empty:

`coap-client -m put -k "SECURITY_CODE" -e '{ "3311": [{ "5850": 0 }] }' "coaps://192.168.0.10:5684/15001/65537"`

Tested using coap-client v4.1.2 and Trådfri Gateway firmware v1.4.15